# Write or draw text on image map

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, imagemap

I have created a image map which contains imageview inside scrollview , in my imageview if touch on particular portion then i want to draw text on that particular portion.

Is there any library for that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this yourself by first getting the point of the touch, like so:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *aTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [aTouch locationInView:self];
    CGFloat xPos = point.x;
    CGFloat yPos = point.y;
}
```

And then use this information and make a method that takes x and y as in parameter. And creates a UITextField programmatically.

```
UITextField * textFieldRounded = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(inParameterX, inParameterY, 300, 50)];
textFieldRounded.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
textFieldRounded.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
textFieldRounded.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
textFieldRounded.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
textFieldRounded.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
textFieldRounded.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
textFieldRounded.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
```

And then add it to your view:

```
[self.view addSubview:textFieldRounded];
```

Depending on what you want to do with the text field, you could make an object instead. And save the to an array perhaps. Well you get the point.